# Серверный рендеринг страниц с помощью Smarty вместо Node.js для React

Tags: php, javascript, reactjs, smarty, шаблонизаторы

Всем привет!

Осваиваю Flux, микропроект - тест-головоломка. Несколько раз в процессе работы приложения есть необходимость полного перестроения страницы с новыми данными(например - смена поля игры на вывод результатов). В этом случае хочу, чтобы пользователю уходила уже готовая страница.

Вопрос - стоит ли использовать Smarty вместо Ноды в связке с React для серверного рендеринга? Какие могут быть подводные камни в этом случае?

С Нодой, знаком очень мало - максимум пользовался npm для webpack.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Я что-то пропустил? `Smarty` - шаблонизатор. `Node.JS` - программная среда. `ReactJS` - библиотека. Подводный камень один - никакой логики. У них даже предназначение различное у всех. Пишите на ноде в связке с реактом, так будет лучше, раз вы с ним хоть чуть чуть знакомы.